# Analytics data not sent

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I set up Analytics according to the [manual](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/analytics/android) and enabled data collection:

`firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);`

Now I try to log a message like this:

`firebase.analytics().logEvent('Test');`

The `google-services.json` has this entry:

`"services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },`

and I linked the GA account with my firebase account. However, log entries don't appear in the firebase pages, and I don't see outgoing message from my app to GA (I'm using a Proxy).

What else could I've missed?